# Google sheets query function comparison operator '<' does not work

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google spreadsheet with some financial information. I want to query that info for the purpose of presenting some summary information. For reasons unknown the 'less than' comparison operator (<) does not work.

Here are the records in the relevant columns:

```
    ID  Status  Val1    Val2
102 Closed  25.18   39.35
103 Closed  89.90   161.35
104 Closed  83.79   110.35
105 Closed  15.17   59.35
106 Closed  85.74   84.69
107 Closed  84.03   156.69
108 Closed  85.50   131.34
109 TBD 33.38   38.3
```

The columns A, B, K & Z correspond to the captioned columns ID, Status, Val1, Val2.

The following query returns no records despite the fact that column Z (with the caption 'Val2') does, indeed, contain values less than 50.

```
=QUERY(Fin!A$4:AC,"select A,B,K,Z where B != 'Open' and Z < 50 order by A asc limit 8",-1)
```

Contrariwise, the following query does work. It returns the expected records with values in column Z greater than 50.

```
=QUERY(Fin!A$4:AC,"select A,B,K,Z where B != 'Open' and Z > 50 order by A asc limit 8",-1)
```

Here is the result of this query:

```
    ID  Status  Val1    Val2
103 Closed  89.90   161.35
104 Closed  83.79   110.35
105 Closed  15.17   59.35
106 Closed  85.74   84.69
107 Closed  84.03   156.69
108 Closed  85.50   131.34
```

Good.

The following query should return all rows but returns none:

```
=QUERY(Fin!A$4:AC,"select A,B,K,Z where B != 'Open' order by A asc limit 8",-1)
```

The main problem is that the greater than comparison operator seems to work, but the less than operator does not. And, after I get that figured out, I would like to understand why the last query does not return all records.

I am mystified. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to the following formula-

```
=QUERY(A:D,"select A,B,C,D where (B <>'Open') and (B is not null) order by A limit 8",1)
```

Not equal `!=` will also work.

```
=QUERY(A:D,"select A,B,C,D where (B !='Open') and (B is not null) order by A limit 8",1)
```

Problem is, you formula returning values correctly but due to `limit 8` it is returning only 8 rows but they all are blanks. So, add another condition `B is not null` which will filter only values removing blank cells.

And finally to filter `D Column`, for your case `Z Column` values less than `50` add another condition to where clause.

```
=QUERY(A:D,"select A,B,C,D 
where (B !='Open') and (B is not null) and (D<50) 
order by A 
limit 8",1)
```

[image]

Comment: You don't really need the parenthesis within the query `=QUERY(A:D,"select A,B,C,D where B !='Open' and B is not null and D<50 order by A limit 8",1)`.

Comment: @marikamitsos I know but to look more cleaner I have wrap those to bracket. Just for fresh look.

Comment: YES! This is why I LOVE StackOverflow! I puzzled  over this for about two hours. Thank you. (BTW, I also like the 'cleaner look' when written with parentheses.)

Comment: @RandallBlake Glad to know. I also suggest to user cleaner look. It will help to understand the formula easily.